# Many to many relationship with friends

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a many to many table which keeps track of friendship.

I need to know that both friends approved each other.

For example, when a person asks to be a friend, their id gets put in self_uuid and the friends in friend_uuid. When the friend approves the request the same thing happens, just the other way around.

[image]

how do find all people that have mutually approved each other?
how do i find all the people that have NOT mutually approved each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutual approval:

```
select f1.self_uuid, f1.friend_uuid
from friends f1
join friends f2 on f1.self_uuid = f2.friend_uuid and f1.friend_uuid = f2.self_uuid
```

Friend requests that have not been approved:

```
select f1.self_uuid, f1.friend_uuid
from friends f1
left join friends f2 on f1.self_uuid = f2.friend_uuid and f1.friend_uuid = f2.self_uuid
where f2.self_uuid is null
```

Comment: wow thanks so much! Is this query expensive btw, performance wise?

Comment: performance should be good if you have a composite index on both columns.